# Two views one model, how to prevent view from unnessary update/rerender

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, redux

**Context**: 
Two views, A and B, are connected to the same model:

- both can change the model state
- both need to update its UI on model
  change

**Question**:
How to prevent view A from re-rendering itself when the model change is triggered by A while still allowing A to update when the model is changed by B?

**Tentative solution:** 
Passing a reference to the view that dispatches the event, similar to event.target

**PS**: We are not using React.js or immutable data. Thus always-re-render or comparing model against view state can be costly and error prone. We are trying to follow the redux pattern by having a single model that contains the entire app state.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is encouraged in backbone. It sounds like something is happening in view A that will cause re-rendering of both view A and view B, but you handle the re-rendering of view A in a different place and therefore don't want it to re-render on the model change event.

If this is the case I think you need view A to listen for changes on a smaller part of the model, like this (from http://backbonejs.org/#Events)

```
book.on({
  "change:author": authorPane.update,
  "change:title change:subtitle": titleView.update,
  "destroy": bookView.remove
});
```

Alternatively you could silence the change event with the `{silent:true}` option when changing the model, and then call the render directly on view B. I don't think this is a good solution though.